# Pass 'this' using bind click event handler to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a  bind event I am tring to call a function but I need to pass `this` to the function:

```
$( 'input.require' ).bind('paste', null, function(e) {
    if(!e.keyCode){
        required(this);
    }
});
```

Here is the function I am calling and this works fine with all my other event handlers.

**Update:** adding `setTimeout` makes it work. Is this ok to do or is there a better way.

```
function required(thisObj){
    setTimeout(function () {
        if($(thisObj).val() != ''){
           $(thisObj).removeClass('input-yellow'); 
        } else {
           $(thisObj).addClass('input-yellow');
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: ok... what is your problem..?

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? This seems to work just fine [on a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DEgQ9/), i.e. paste on an empty field adds the class, paste on a non-empty field removes the class. Perhaps you're looking for something different?

Answer (score 0):

In require you just need to refer to it

```
function required(myOldThis){
   //use myOldThis here
}
```

Comment: ok i think i know what is going on when i paste the function i am caliing runs before the paste is doen and i get the else part of my if statement so i add settimout and it works in my require function  is there a better way

Answer (score 0):

```
$( 'input.require' ).bind('paste', null, function(e) {
    var myObj = $(this)[0];
    if(!e.keyCode){
        required(myObj);
    }
});
```